# Google Workspace Marketplace listing for firebase mobile app

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

My flutter based mobile app is on Firebase and I want to publish on Google Apps Marketplace so user can login with google and have user install the mobile app from web app. Is this possible? If yes, can you please advise how to configure on Google Workspace Marketplace SDK/API?